# How to analyze btsnoop_hci.log (bluetooth/android/wireshark)

Tags: android, bluetooth, wireshark, android-bluetooth

I am using an android app (Feiyu ON) to controll a camera gimbal (Feiyu MG lite) manualy over bluetooth (virtual joystick for rotate right/left/up/down).

However, I would like to rotate only one step every 10 seconds for example (To do some epic timelapse!).
I thought about getting the commands that are used for rotation and build an Android app by myself.

First try was to setup another bluetooth device with an terminal, name it like the gimbal and log all commands. But the Feiyu ON-app did not like to connect to my device.

Second hope was to log all Bluetooth communications on my phone (SGS7) and analyze the btsnoop_hci.log with wireshark. Thats were you could help. I do not understand all those handshakes and commonication packages, could someone have a quick look and tell me what i am looking for?

Steps i logged:
- connect to device,rotate left with virtual joystick, wait, rotate again

Also, do you have another idea how to realize my dream?

Thanks a lot, even if you only read through all of my bad explanations :)

My btsnoop_hci.log:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/4jzi2i76t6b5m2j/btsnoop_hci.log?dl=0

Answer (score 0):

It uses bluetooth LE. I think it will be better to look into Feiyu ON app first. Fresh versions are obfuscated by LLVM, but it is possible to find an older version on some alternative app stores (it looks like at least version 2.0.6 is not obfuscated).
Upd: oh, it obfuscated also, but only partially and not by such sofisticated tool.